# Is there a way that i can highlight or colour various table rows based on data entered in textfield?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

What i'm trying to do it's highlight the serial number that i scan from a box of items.

So when i scan the S/N. My idea is that the table, which contains the items in the box, change their color. My english sucks, so i think images can explain my idea in a better way.

So my code does the following:

First i load the table with the info from the box 1 ("Gaveta"):

[http://prntscr.com/o4ykdy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai0WX.png)

Then when i filter the S/N of the item in the box:

[http://prntscr.com/o4yly4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diSGO.png)

i face my problem, the search paints the correct S/N but it damages my tablemodel.

My code:

Data search:

public void buscarNumeroSerie (String nserie)
    {
     try {

```
             String [] campos={"NUMERO_SERIE","MARCA","GAVETA"};
             String filtroNS = nserie;
             String NSSQL = "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM"
                     + "(SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_wd "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_toshiba "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_seagate "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_samsung "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_hitachi )"
                     + "AS TROUBLE WHERE NUMERO_SERIE LIKE '%"+filtroNS+"%'";

            System.out.println(NSSQL); 
                    nsconn = metodosPool.dataSource.getConnection();
                    //ModeloTablaLista = new DefaultTableModel(null, campos);
                    stmnt = nsconn.prepareStatement(NSSQL);
                    ResultSet nsrs = stmnt.executeQuery(NSSQL);
                    String [] nsfila = null;
            //if(nsrs.next()== true){
             //       String [] nsfila = new String[3];



                while (nsrs.next())
                    {   
                        nsfila = new String[3];
                        nsfila[0]=nsrs.getString("Numero_Serie");
                        nsfila[1]=nsrs.getString("Marca");
                        nsfila[2]=nsrs.getString("Gaveta");
                       // ModeloTablaLista.addRow(nsfila);
                    }

                if (nsfila == null) 
                    {
                               Object[] opcionesPurga = {"Agregar Disco Hitachi",
                                   "Agregar Disco Toshiba",
                                   "Agregar Disco Seagate",
                                   "Agregar Disco Samsung",
                                   "Agregar Disco WD",
                                   "Omitir"};

                               int sinDiscoEnTabla = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog
                                            (rootPane, 
                                            "Disco no encontrado, ¿que desea hacer?:", 
                                            "Disco no encontrado", 
                                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                                            null, 
                                            opcionesPurga,
                                            opcionesPurga[1]);

                               System.out.println(sinDiscoEnTabla);

                    switch (sinDiscoEnTabla){

                            case 0:
                            sinDiscoAddHi.setVisible(true);
                            break;

                            case 1:
                            sinDiscoAddTo.setVisible(true);    
                            break;

                            case 2:
                            sinDiscoAddSe.setVisible(true);      
                            break;

                            case 3:
                            sinDiscoAddHi.setVisible(true);        
                            break;

                            case 4:
                            sinDiscoAddWD.setVisible(true);        
                            break;

                            case 5:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Por favor ingrese un nuevo disco:");  
                            tfNumeroSeriePurga.setText("");
                            break;
                    }
                    }
                nsrs.close();
                        stmnt.close();
                       // tablaDiscosGaveta.setModel(ModeloTablaLista);
                        ClaseColor colorear = new ClaseColor(0);
                        tablaDiscosGaveta.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(colorear);
           }

           //else
           //  {

            //    System.err.println("No existen datos asociados");
            //         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Disco no encontrado, quiere:");
           //    } 


catch (SQLException nseerr) 
                    {
                      System.err.println(""+nseerr.getSQLState());
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al buscar \n"
                      +nseerr, "Error en la operacion ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }                    

}
```

Table Renderer:

public class ClaseColor extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

```
private final int patron;  

public ClaseColor(int patron) {
    this.patron = patron;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
           (JTable tablaDiscosGaveta, 
            Object value, 
            boolean Selected, 
            boolean hasFocus, 
            int row, 
            int col) 
    {

    if (!tfNumeroSeriePurga.getText().equals(tablaDiscosGaveta.getValueAt(row, patron).toString())) 

    {
        System.out.println("FramePurgar.PurgarDiscos1.ClaseColor.methodName()"+"no pille nada !");
    } 
   else
    {
        setForeground(Color.RED);
        //setFont(font);
        //
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(tablaDiscosGaveta, value, Selected, hasFocus, row, col);
        return this;
    }
```

return this;

}
 }

What i'm trying to do is paint every S/N that matchs with the textField "Serial Number" which does the search.

Something like this:

[http://prntscr.com/o4ynui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3fcA.png)

so any new S/N i search, get a mark while i keep scanning S/N, and then the S/N that are not marked, are eliminated from the table.

Comment: Maybe use a Filter to show only the rows containing the test you are searching for. This way you don't need to scroll through the entire table to find the highlighted text. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for and example that does the filtering as you type in a text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final update at this, i fixed my problem changing the value at the following line:

```
   Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(tablaDiscosGaveta, col, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, row, col);
```

for

```
        Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(tablaDiscosGaveta, value, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, row, col);
```

[Finally !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGGaP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not giving us a [minimal-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i have created my own example in order to show you how this could be done. Using underline to a `JTable` would be tricky since (I think) JTextPane is required. However, it is easier to achieve something similar by highlighting the search text in the cell of the table. Of course in order to do that we need to create our own custom [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html).

**Code:**

```
public class TableExample extends JFrame {
    private static final Color HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    private JTextField textField;

    TableExample() {
        String data[][] = { { "101", "Mike", "17" }, { "102", "Thomas", "21" }, { "103", "Brian", "42" }, { "104", "George", "24" } };
        String column[] = { "ID", "NAME", "AGE" };

        JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        JTable table = new JTable();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table); // You were not adding the sp into your panel, take care that next time.
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, column); // Create the model with our data.
        table.setModel(dtm);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CellHighlightRenderer());

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                table.repaint();

            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                table.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                table.repaint();
            }
        });

        inputpanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        inputpanel.add(sp);

        add(inputpanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
    }

    class CellHighlightRenderer extends JTextField implements TableCellRenderer {
        public DefaultHighlighter high = new DefaultHighlighter();
        public DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlight_painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);

        public CellHighlightRenderer() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            setHighlighter(high);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
            setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());

            setFont(table.getFont());
            setValue(value);
            int pos = 0;
            String word = textField.getText();
            word = word.toLowerCase();// In order to improve search?
            String stringValue = value.toString();
            stringValue = stringValue.toLowerCase(); // In order to improve search?
            if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                if ((pos = stringValue.indexOf(word, pos)) >= 0) {
                    try {
                        high.addHighlight(pos, pos + word.length(), highlight_painter);
                        pos += word.length();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        protected void setValue(Object value) {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TableExample te = new TableExample();
            te.setVisible(true);
        });

    }
}
```

---

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: This helped me a lot, the execution was similar so i used that. Thanks so much!

Comment: @AlexisAhumada I am glad that it helped you. But i think you mark as correct the wrong answer thought. :P

Answer (score 0):

Well i could actually do what i want, now i have to refine some details.

First is the renderer code:

```
 public class ClaseColor extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

private final int patronSerie;

public ClaseColor(int patron) {
    this.patronSerie = patron;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
           (JTable tablaDiscosGaveta, 
            Object value, 
            boolean Selected, 
            boolean hasFocus, 
            int row, 
            int col) 
    {
    Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(tablaDiscosGaveta, col, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, row, col);

    for (int i = 0; i < tablaDiscosGaveta.getRowCount(); i++) 
    {
                        if(tablaDiscosGaveta.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().equals(tfNumeroSeriePurga.getText()))
                        {
                        System.out.println("El número si existe");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        System.out.println("El número no existe");
                        }

    if (!tablaDiscosGaveta.isRowSelected(row))
            {
                comp.setBackground(getBackground());
                                    int modelRow = tablaDiscosGaveta.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                if(tablaDiscosGaveta.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().equals(tfNumeroSeriePurga.getText()))
                                    {
                comp.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            }
    }}return this;}
```

then i apply it to the table

```
nsrs.close();
                        stmnt.close();
                        tablaDiscosGaveta.setModel(ModeloTablaLista);
                        ClaseColor comp = new ClaseColor(0);                            
                        tablaDiscosGaveta.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(comp);

           }
```

with this i could filter and set the background green when i match the filter.

but it shows only "zeroes" when is filtering, so i need to fix that.

[Filter is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02dGs.jpg)

[It shows the background i wanted but not the serial i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRhUm.jpg)